# Why is zip default compression on Mac

Tags: compression

Mac is based on Linux so why would it use zip as default compression, if zip stores MSDOS file attributes.

[Which is more efficient - tar or zip compression? What is the difference between tar and zip?](https://superuser.com/questions/173756/which-is-more-efficient-tar-or-zip-compression-what-is-the-difference-between)

Comment: almost certianly because Zip is freely licensed and supported on pretty much every modern system: http://www.info-zip.org/license.html And Mac is based on Unix (BSD) not Linux. And Zip supports FAT file attributes. Its not really correct to characterize them as MSDOS's.